# Importing top-level modules of same name from different egg files

Tags: python, swagger-codegen

I have autogenerated code from [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen). The directory structure looks like this:

```
swagger1 
├── docs
├── git_push.sh
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── swagger_client
│   ├── __init__.py
├── test
├── test-requirements.txt
└── tox.ini
```

I generate an egg file from this as `swagger1.egg`. Similarly, I generate another directory swagger2 and generate another `swagger2.egg`. So both the eggs have the modules named `swagger_client`.
Currently, I import and use the egg as

```
sys.path.append("~/swagger1.egg")
import swagger_client
```

Currently, there seems no way to change the name of the module `swagger_client` while generation as per [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8738) issue.
Is there a way to use swagger_client from the other egg as well? I an using python 2.7.

Comment: Maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path  for P2 there's `import imp; imp.load_source()` if you're just looking for a way to hack around your development environment.. btw.. p2 is old.

Comment: @Todd Doesn't work for egg files